# Magento Community version

Tags: magento-community

Hello I am about to build an online shop for a client of mine and I want to know which version is currently (November 2016) the best one to use. Which has more themes? Which one is more stable? Which one has more extensions? I mostly interested to know the difference in using 1.9.x versnio as opposed to new 2.x version.

Thanks

Comment: Always use the latest version.

Comment: Doesn't the 1.9.3 version still a little buggy ? (if he choose Magento 1.x)

Comment: @7ochem This is not duplicate question. The duplicate question that you linked discuss about the magento 1.x version. But here he is asking whether he/she needs to opt M1 or M2 and why. This is basically an opinion based question.

Comment: @RajeevKTomy true, just wanted to have it as a reference as Cladiuss is mentioning it in a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the latest version of Magento 1.9.x because there are a lot of extensions available for this version.

You can also use the latest version of Magento 2.x but there are not as many extensions available as Magento 1.9.x because Magento 2.x has been recently introduced.

You can also refer some blogs.

1. http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/moving-from-magento-1-to-magento-2/
2. https://www.shopping-cart-migration.com/blog/42-magento/43708-the-key-differences-between-magento-1x-and-20

Answer (score 1):

**Give preference to 1.x versions.**

Most of extentions and themes of magento connect store are for Mangeto versions 1.x.

**And about 2,**

it is newly introduced version,
so for freshsers and beginners 1.x versions are probably more comfortable for working

Answer (score 0):

Magento1.9.x is best for now, many no of extensions are available in the market and problem solution easily found for version 1.9.x

Magento 2.x is available with bugs, less extension in market and less problem solution.